# How do I allow my Agrarian Skies server to run?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-java-edition-server, server-administration

I've uploaded and installed the Agaraian Skies modpack onto my server, hosted by [MTXserv](https://www.mtxserv.fr).

When I start my server, it always reverts back to 'stopped' and every time I try to run it, the server comes up with the following error:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/" "read")
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Could you post a the logs? What control panel does your hosting service use and... Did you install it correctly? (Uploading and the hitting 'run' won't work.) | **Also, there are many things that could make your server unstartable. Could you at least clarify it?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's for modded minecraft tech support and we can only help with vanilla minecraft crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You've uploaded the server to the filesystem *root* not the server *root*.

The reason that it cannot run is that you have installed the server into a read-only area of the system, where all your hosts' main server programs are kept. (ie. The thing that controls your permissions, the control panel etc.)

You have to upload it into your server root, which depending on the setup should be in different locations. **Contact your hosting company's support for more information about this.**

For example, my server setups have multiple folders inside the `servers` ("customers"* don't see this via FTP, it simply displays as the 'root') folder. They are the IPs of the servers that are running (of course; you would only be able to see your *own* server(s)' folder. (ie. a server running on 127.0.0.1:25565 would be in a folder called `127.0.0.1_25565`)

The server files can only run if it is inside that folder (or any of the other server folders), not outside... Unless I manually start the file from the console (ie. Remote Desktop)

*I run these programs straight on my computers. So it'd be natural that there's only be one user; me.

Comment: thx but i h've this error : java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/" "read")

Comment: This is a generic Java error: Your server program cannot read anything at all (mod files, worlds, player data etc.) as it does not have any read/write permissions. - You'll need to contact your hosting company to solve this.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have access to your server machine (as in not via a web console, but the machine literally in front of you/remote desktop), try running java with elevated permissions (as an administrator/superuser).

Comment: ok my support say the same as you but no issue to this problem it's a problem with a mod who wan't access to root directory (forbiden for security reason)

Comment: @KywarL What's that mod's name?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the person in charge of mTxServ support. As I answered to Kywar, the problem is caused by the  mod Hardcore Quest trying to reach "/". It must be an error related to absolute paths and not a security issue, as far as I know it's the only mod or plugin having this problem.

I hope HQ's devs will fix this, on our side we don't have any workaround so far :(